# How can I create a label encoder utilizing only numpy (and not sklearn LabelEncoder)?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to recreate something similar to the 
`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`

However I do not want to use `sklearn` or `pandas`. I would like to only use `numpy` and the Python standard library. Here's what I would like to achieve:

```py
import numpy as np
input = np.array([['hi', 'there'],
                     ['scott', 'james'],
                     ['hi', 'scott'],
                     ['please', 'there']])

# Output would look like
np.ndarray([[0, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [0, 2],
            [2, 0]])
```

It would also be great to be able to map it back as well, so a result would then look exactly like the input again.

If this were in a spreadsheet, the input would look like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the logic? Why 'there' maps to 0?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Simon - I am reducing my dependency on sklearn

Comment: @DaniMesejo - I made a typo there. It should be good now. The logic is that I am doing this "by column"

Comment: Does it matter that the labels are in order, or just that the labels are unique to the values?

Comment: @ALollz - I don't care about the order so long as I can map everything back. Imagine a neural network where you want the output to be labeled as an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple comprehension, using the `return_inverse` result from `np.unique`

```
arr = np.array([['hi', 'there'], ['scott', 'james'],
                ['hi', 'scott'], ['please', 'there']])

np.column_stack([np.unique(arr[:, i], return_inverse=True)[1] for i in range(arr.shape[1])])

array([[0, 2],
       [2, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

---

Or applying along the axis:

```
np.column_stack(np.apply_along_axis(np.unique, 0, arr, return_inverse=True)[1])
```

Comment: This is really close, however, the output array is not quite accurate because it blends the uniques across columns.

Comment: @ScottStoltzman sorry what do you mean? Do you need to map the values of each column separately, or do you need to map each value regardless of where it belongs to a unique identifier?  Given you expected output, this seems to be what you want (a unique mapping for each column separately) unless i'm missing something? The numbers are just differerent because `np.unique` sorts, so the labeling is based alphabetically, not by occurrence.

Comment: yes, each column separately. The current solution solves for the entire array, I would want it by column (axis=1 type of thing)

Comment: @ScottStoltzman no it doesn't because the list comprehension takes each column separately. AFAIK, np.unique doesn't have a default parameter to act on individual values in an axis. You can either find uniue values, or unique things per axis (i.e. in a 2D array unique rows or unique columns). I'll add a solution with `np.apply_along_axis`, but it's not really different

Comment: You can see that `'scott'` in the first column is labeled with 2, but in the second column it's labeled with 1, so it's treating each separately.

Comment: you are exactly right, the first answer is correct! Sorry about misreading that.

Answer (score 2):

Was talking to @Scott Stoltzmann and spit balled about a way to reverse the accepted answer.

One can either carry the original `arr` along with them through out their program or record the mappings for each column. If you do the latter, here's some simple non-performant code to do so:

```
l = []

for real_column, encoded_column in zip(np.column_stack(arr), np.column_stack(arr2)):    
    d = {}
    for real_element, encoded_element in zip(real_column, encoded_column):
        d[encoded_element] = real_element
    l.append(d)
print(l)
```

Doing this with the above yields:

> [{0: 'hi', 2: 'scott', 1: 'please'}, {2: 'there', 0: 'james', 1: 'scott'}]

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, which is both beautiful (almost) and optimal:

```py
labels = np.array([['hi', 'there'], ['scott', 'james'],
                   ['hi', 'scott'], ['please', 'there']])

indexes = {val: idx for idx, val in enumerate(np.unique(labels))}
encoded = np.array([indexes[val] for val in labels.flatten()]).reshape(labels.shape)

print(f'Indexes: {indexes}')
print(f'Encoded labels: {encoded}')
```

The output:

```
Indexes: {'hi': 0, 'james': 1, 'please': 2, 'scott': 3, 'there': 4}
Encoded labels: [[0 4]
 [3 1]
 [0 3]
 [2 4]]
```

Enjoy the labels encoder ;)